# angular 6 store data from json array inside json

Tags: javascript, angular, mongodb, observable, mean

I have this get method

```
     this.data.getCoffee(params['id'], response => {
              this.coffee = response;
            });
```

and the out of response  is

```
coffeetype:"frappe"
location:Array(1)
0:{_id: "5b7327a3adcdbc1a80b7861f", address: " adres 5", city: "city5", 
latitude: 21.1211546, longitude: 79.1291045}
 length:1
__proto__:Array(0)
name:"coffee5 "
notes:"note5"
place:"place 5"
rating:7
tastingRating:Array(1)
0:{_id: "5b7327a3adcdbc1a80b7861e", aroma: 6, flavor: 6, intensity: 6, 
aftertaste: 5}
length:1
__proto__:Array(0)
__v:0
_id:"5b7327a2adcdbc1a80b7861d"
```

but when I save this to the instance of this.coffee = response 
only name, type, notes, and overall tating get to the coffee 
the tastingArray and locationarray do not get into the array instance of coffee

coffee.ts

```
import { TastingRating } from './TastingRating';
import { PlaceLocation } from './PlaceLocation';

export class Coffee {
 _id: string;
coffeetype: string;

rating: number;
notes: string;
tastingRating: TastingRating;

constructor (
public  name: string = '',
public  place: string= ''  ,
public  location: PlaceLocation = null
) {

  this.location = new PlaceLocation();
  this.tastingRating = new TastingRating();
}
}
```

placelocation.ts

```
 constructor(
 public address: string = '',
 public city: string = '',
 public latitude: number = null,
 public longitude: number = null,
  ) {

  }
```

tastingRating.ts

```
 export class TastingRating {

   aroma: number;
   flavor: number;
   intensity: number;
   sweetness: number;
   aftertaste: number;

  }
```

I am using MongoDB as backend
if I use this.coffee.location.city it shows undefined
even response.location.city says undefined from get method

Comment: Please format your post better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model **coffee.ts**, `location` and `tastingRating` are not arrays, but in the JSON you are receiving, those properties are arrays.

Change the types of `location` and `tastingRating` to arrays of their respective types and it should work.

**coffee.ts:**

```
import { TastingRating } from './TastingRating';
import { PlaceLocation } from './PlaceLocation';

export class Coffee {
 _id: string;
coffeetype: string;

rating: number;
notes: string;
tastingRating: TastingRating[]; // changed to array

constructor (
public  name: string = '',
public  place: string= ''  ,
public  location: PlaceLocation[] = null // changed to array
) {

  this.location = new Array<PlaceLocation>(); // creating array of PlaceLocation type
  this.tastingRating = new Array<TastingRating>(); // creating array of TastingRating type
}
}
```

Also, `_id` property is missing in both **PlaceLocation** and **TastingRating** classes. Add this property to both these classes.

In the response you are receiving, `sweetness` property of **TastingRating** class is missing. Have the response include this property or make it optional, like `sweetness?: number;`

Comment: So I did this things with this i had to add array value to my html code like this     [(ngModel)]="coffee.location[0].address"  but this is giving me error address is not defined but the value shows in view

Answer (score 0):

As per your response, response.location is an array. So you need to look for exact array value

```js
this.coffee.location[0].city
```

Comment: i got the value with this method but i am having error on compile time now          Cannot read property 'city' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

The properties for tastingrating and placelocation being retrieved don't match your database's response. The database response is missing a value for property sweetness on tastingrating and both classes do not have a value for _id, therefore typescript is unable to assign the retrieved values to them.

If you add an _id field to both classes just as you have already done in coffee.ts and add the sweetness field to your database, it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

so considering everything above i got the issue i was having was that i was getting an array for testingRating and location . what  I did was just declare those two with the there respected arrays from response directly as follows

```
this.coffee = response;
this.coffee.location = response.location[0];
this.coffee.tastingRating = response.tastingRating[0];
```

I don't know if this is a right thing to do but this worked properly
so please let me know your thoughts.